# Trouble creating scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm having trouble using the scatter to create a scatter plot. Can someone help me? I've highlighted the line causing the error:

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

data = pd.read_csv('vetl8.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
clusterNum = 3
X = df.iloc[:, 1:].values
X = np.nan_to_num(X)
Clus_dataSet = StandardScaler().fit_transform(X)
k_means = KMeans(init="k-means++", n_clusters=clusterNum, n_init=12)
k_means.fit(X)
labels = k_means.labels_
df["Labels"] = labels

df.to_csv('dfkmeans.csv')
plt.scatter(df[2], df[1], c=labels) **#Here**
plt.xlabel('K', fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel('g', fontsize=16)
plt.show()
#data set correct
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close, just a minor adjustment to access the x-y columns by number should fix it:

```
plt.scatter(df[df.columns[2]], df[df.columns[1]], c=df["Labels"])
```

Comment: @MarcusViniciusAmbiel that is great, please kindly accept the answer if this worked for you